# How can I deploy a Vue app into a subdirectory?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I've got a somewhat involved build pipeline... I am using a static site generator to build my site. This deploys to a "public" directory and is generating the  stub inside of an index.html in a generated folder, test.

For example:

mysite/public/test/index.html (contains the div stub for the app).

However, using vue-cli-service build wants to attach the Vue code and app to mysite/public/index.html. I want it instead to update public/test/index.html.

How can I configure this? I'm thinking it might have something to do with the Multi Page App setup, but I'm not technically doing a multi page app. It's really an SPA but living in a subdirectory.

Thanks.

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl

Answer (score 3):

Vue CLI can be configured with a [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) to specify a base path where your project will be deployed. For your desired path, create [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) in the root of your project directory, and insert this config:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/public/test/'
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for. This solution takes everything in the public directory and tries to turn it into a single page app and deploy it to my "public/test" directory. I think I'll have to take the output from the build command, and manually move it to the subdirectory of the static site that I'm generating.